# C++ GetKeyState with a string

Tags: c++

I need your help for C ++, I need to use a GetKeyState with a string
Example (does not work) :

```
string test = "0x47" // G Key for examble(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)
GetKeyState(test)
{
   cout << "Nice << endl;
}
```

I would just like to know how to use the GetKeyState function with a string instead of the key (GetKeyState (string) instead of: GetKeyState (0x47))

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Does it compile? Does it give the wrong output?

Comment: I mean it's a a draft (the code I put for the example is a diagram)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you need to have some code (not pseudocode) that has some issue you can't solve. Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would just like to know how to use the GetKeyState function with a string instead of the virtual code key (GetKeyState(test) instead of GetKeyState (0x47))

Comment: You could do `GetKeyState (std::stoi (mystring))`

Comment: it does not work, when i press the key the code does not execute

Comment: You can't call `GetKeyState` with a string. Its first parameter is an `int`. You could create a function `int f(string)` and call `GetKeyState(f(test))`. One possible function is `std::stoi` as you can see in Paul Sanders' comment. Your string contains a number in hex format. Try `GetKeyState (std::stoi (mystring, 0, 0))`

Comment: Why do you want to use a string and not an `int` like: `int test = 0x47; GetKeyState(test);`?

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand what you are explaining to me, can you give me an example?

Comment: Why do you want to use a string that contains a number in hex format? It would be much easier to use an integer: `int test = 0x47;`.

Comment: because I made a code that allows me with an .ini file to bind keys, but it works with strings and I can't use the strings in the GetKeyState function

Comment: You have to convert the string to an int, e.g. with [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetKeyState()` takes an `int` as input, not a string. So you MUST parse the string to convert it into an `int`, there is no other option.

There are many ways to do that parsing in C++, eg:

- `std::stoi()`:

```
#include <string>

std::string test = "0x47";
int value = std::stoi(test, nullptr, 0/*or 16*/);
GetKeyState(value)
```

- `std::sscanf()`:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

std::string test = "0x47";
int value = 0;
std::sscanf(test.c_str(), "%x", &value);
GetKeyState(value)
```

- `std::istringstream`:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string test = "0x47";
int value = 0;
std::istringstream(test) >> std::hex >> value;
GetKeyState(value)
```

Just to name a few.